# Request.Form works only on name tags?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, namevaluecollection

I am developing a very simple data entry application (in bootstrap) using ASP.net and VB.Net as code behind in Visual Studio 2012 web.

Suppose that i have the following html to get the firstname:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="padding:20px">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" style="max-width:450px" maxlength="60" />
        <small class="text-muted">Enter your first name.</small>
      </div>
      <button runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="btnSubmit_ServerClick" >Submit</button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

and the corresponding code behind to handle its value:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim fname As String = Request.Form("firstname").ToString
End Sub
```

Suppose that I don't want to use `runat="server"` in my html firstname field. 
I see that `Request.Form("firstname").ToString` only works when I have set the tag `name="firstname"`. If I have set only the `id` tag (and NOT the `name` tag) it does not take it into account; in my case if I have only `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="" style="max-width:450px" maxlength="60" />` the `Request.Form("firstname")` in my server side, returns NULL.

I also try `Request.Form` with no luck. I see that the collection `NameValueCollection` is filled by components that have set only the `name` tag.

And my question is, is it possible to change my server code in order to work with html components that they have set their ID only?

Comment: I would recommend to use [server controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1.aspx) (text box, button, etc.) so that you can strongly-typed access their values.

Comment: No, over the requests you will only get namevalue pairs, the id is not something that is sent to the server

Comment: @UweKeim thanks for your suggestion. 
I agree, but my question is just for knowledge purposes, granted that we have existing code with hundreds of html fields set this way.

Comment: The joys of maintaining legacy code…

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for your answer. This is something that lead us to find a work around... ;)

Comment: @UweKeim Exactly my friend... :s !

Answer (score 2):

When you opt out of using server-side controls, you're left with the Request collection method of reading the values.

The code behind will only be able to read the data sent to the back-end. If you inspect your request (the page requested when you submit the form) in the Network tab of your favorite browser, you will find a section showing the data sent. And since you're not setting a name on that input field, the data is NOT sent to the server. That is why you cannot read it. The ID has no impact on what is sent to the server. The ID is ment only for client-side useage. The reason it "works" when you add Runat="server" is because the framework add information to the secret hidden input field named "__VIEWSTATE" (or something).

So in the end, the way HTML works, when you submit a form, all input elements are sent in the form name=value and since you omit the name, no data is sent.

Like the comments below your post suggests, you really should consider using the server-side controls (runat="server") or add the name tag to your form elements.

I know a lot of people don't like asp.net webforms (actually i'm not a fan either), but there are other alternatives - a logic shift would be to move to asp.net mvc instead. Whatever you do, if you opt out of the framework specifics you have to comply with the html5 standart.

Good luck :)